# Nicer display of output with TeXForm

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, latex, output

I am summing some terms by first transforming it to  `TeXForm`.

Example:

```
Sum[TeXForm[x^i],{i,1,50}]
```

[image]
I want to break the line in the notebook output (or in `OutputForm`)
starting with `+` instead of a trailing `+` as in the previous output.
I can set `PageWidth` with `TeXForm` but this does not help.
Mathematica does it to further process this output (if any).
Otherwise a leading `+` would mean each of these lines are separate expression (which is not true and unwanted)!

**My question is, just for displaying purposes can I show the line break with a leading `+` instead of a trailing "+"?**

The expected output will look something like the below:

```
  x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8 + x^9 + x^10 + x^11 + x^12 + x^13 + x^14 + x^15 
+ x^16 + x^17 + x^18 + x^19 + x^20 + x^21 + x^22 + x^23 + x^24 + x^25 + x^26 
+ x^27 + x^28 + x^29 + x^30 + x^31 + x^32 + x^33 + x^34 + x^35 + x^36 + x^37 + x^38 
+ x^39 + x^40 + x^41 + x^42 + x^43 + x^44 + x^45 + x^46 + x^47 + x^48 + x^49 + x^50
```

Note: The expected output is not meant to be used for further manipulation in the Notebook. It is for convenience for display and also if I want to take (copy) the output into LaTeX where a leading `+` is preferred instead of a trailing `+`.
Also, I am not interested in using `TeXForm[Sum[x^i, {i, 1, 50}]]`.

Comment: `TeXForm` is meant for generating `Latex` to be typeset by your Latex compiler. Why are you using it to display things in the notebook? Why not use `TraditionalForm` instead?

Comment: I understand by using `Sum` I am doing a Mathematica manipulation for which a trailing `+` is needed. My goal is to prepare a custom TeXForm where complicated and long expressions can be nicely written directly from Mathematica. Hence the `Sum` comes since I am splitting the expression into pieces, beautifying each piece and finally summing it together.  As a result `TraditionalForm` won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ToBoxes[Sum[TeXForm[x^i], {i, 1, 50}]];
ReplacePart[%, 
  Position[%, "+"][[10 ;; -1 ;; 10]] -> "\n+"] // RawBoxes
```

---

```
x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}
+x^{11}+x^{12}+x^{13}+x^{14}+x^{15}+x^{16}+x^{17}+x^{18}+x^{19}+x^{20}
+x^{21}+x^{22}+x^{23}+x^{24}+x^{25}+x^{26}+x^{27}+x^{28}+x^{29}+x^{30}
+x^{31}+x^{32}+x^{33}+x^{34}+x^{35}+x^{36}+x^{37}+x^{38}+x^{39}+x^{40}
+x^{41}+x^{42}+x^{43}+x^{44}+x^{45}+x^{46}+x^{47}+x^{48}+x^{49}+x^{50}
```

---

```
ToBoxes[Sum[TeXForm[x^i], {i, 1, 50}]];
ReplacePart[%, Position[%, "+"][[5 ;; -1 ;; 5]] -> "\n+"] // RawBoxes
```

---

```
x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5
+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}
+x^{11}+x^{12}+x^{13}+x^{14}+x^{15}
+x^{16}+x^{17}+x^{18}+x^{19}+x^{20}
+x^{21}+x^{22}+x^{23}+x^{24}+x^{25}
+x^{26}+x^{27}+x^{28}+x^{29}+x^{30}
+x^{31}+x^{32}+x^{33}+x^{34}+x^{35}
+x^{36}+x^{37}+x^{38}+x^{39}+x^{40}
+x^{41}+x^{42}+x^{43}+x^{44}+x^{45}
+x^{46}+x^{47}+x^{48}+x^{49}+x^{50}
```